# Prove that $(1+x)\ln(1+x) >\arctan(x)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

My solution is that slope of $\ln(1+x)$ is greater than $\arctan(x)/(1+x)$ & at $x=0$ both of these are equal and hence inequality proved. **What i am looking for is the restrictions on $x$ in which this inequality is valid**. Alternate solutions are also welcome !

Comment: x>-1  or x>0 ?  or something else

Answer (score 3):

Another way, would be to consider $f(x) = (1+x)\log(1+x)-\tan^{-1} x$.  Clearly this is defined only for $x > -1$.  For this domain, 
$$f'(x) = \log(1+x)+1 - \frac1{1+x^2}, \implies f'(0) = 0$$

$$\implies  f''(x) = \frac1{1+x}+\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac{1+2x+4x^2+x^4}{(1+x)(1+x^2)^2} > 0$$
as the denominator is positive in this domain, and $1+x^2\ge 2 \lvert x \rvert$ by AM-GM.

Thus $f(x)$ is convex, so it remains above the tangent at $x=0$, which is $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$if \\x>2 \rightarrow  (1+x)\ln(1+x)>(1+2)\ln(3) >3*1=3 \\so\\ \frac{ -\pi }{ 2 }<\arctan x <\frac{ \pi }{ 2 }\\3>\pi/2\\x>2 \rightarrow (1+x)\ln(1+x)>\arctan x$$

Comment: for -1<x<2  you can use tailor series ,I think